# all ubuntu commands results in GLIBC_2.30 not found

Tags: boot, command-line, 18.04, lubuntu, system

I wanted to install openssh on a machine (offline ubuntu 18.04) so I logged into another machine with ubuntu 20.04 and I downloaded the packages only using the --download-only option, when I went and installed these packages on the offline machine, the system stopped working, I booted into a liveUbuntuCD, mounted the drive and used chroot to try to fix the system but any command (ls, sudo, dpkg,...etc) gives me the same output, which is: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.30' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1)

anyone can help fix this issue please ?

Comment: Do you have a list of the packages from 20.04 you installed? Does `dpkg` or `apt` still work?

Comment: Hello. There are no such verison of Ubuntu as 18 and 20.

Comment: @vidarlo dpkg no, not working, produce the same error, apt works but it can't do nothing because it detects that there is some packages that needs fixing, suggesting to run --fix-broken but when I do I get an "unable to correct dependencies" error (resolve generated breaks, this may be cause by held packages)

I have list of packages but it's too long to be posted here

Comment: @David I meant 18.04 LTS and 20.04 LTS

Comment: You've basically broken a lot by installing conflicting libraries. Restoring your system is *possible*, but I would suggest that you simply reinstall it. Take a copy of `/home`, and put that back in place after reinstall.

Comment: In the future, you can download packages for 18.04 from https://packages.ubuntu.com to avoid conflicting versions. This will also list which packages are dependencies and you can cross reference to see which dependencies are already installed or needed on the 18.04 computer.

Answer (score 0):

Mixing packages from different Ubuntu releases causes dependency problems and version conflicts like those you are experiencing now. The only safe way of recovering from that is to reinstall the system, sticking to packages from a single release.